# android google calendar .. application force close

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access the google calendar using gdata. but the application closes :(
I have added gdata-client-1.0.jar as external jar.

here are my files :
rrr.java
    package caleda.qwe;

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService;
import com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarFeed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class rrr extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String res="not proper";
     // Create a CalenderService and authenticate
        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("calendar");
        try{
        myService.setUserCredentials("sunnycool333", "XXXXX");

        // Send the request and print the response
        URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
        CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
      //  System.out.println("Calendars you own:");
       // System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
          CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
        //  System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
          res=entry.getTitle().getPlainText();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            //System.out.println("not working");
            res=e.toString();
        }

        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        view.setText(res);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

applicationmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="caleda.qwe"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".rrr"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Can someone please help me in pointing out my mistake.

Comment: what is the error you are getting in Logcat?

Comment: Why didn't you paste the error log? That has the actual error inside, and will point to the place where something (like a nullpointerexception?) happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity may be failing with the [Application Not Responding](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html#anr) dialog because you are making a network access on the UI thread.

Try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122714/android-progressdialog-with-threading-problem/5122836) has some example code and links concerning AsyncTask.

Comment: 03-06 16:27:40.259: ERROR/dalvikvm(3252): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
03-06 16:30:04.759: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3316): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-06 16:30:06.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3329): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-06 16:30:06.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3335): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception ....... etc.....
03-06 16:30:06.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3335):     ... 14 more
03-06 16:30:06.910: ERROR/dalvikvm(3335): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone..

If we add two more files as external jar files the problem gets solved..

The two files are located in "deps" folder of gdata client src..
named : google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar & jsr305.jar